# Not able to select options from side menu and navigate to different screens

Tags: java, android-studio

I have made one dashboard screen in that screen I added side bar navigation so for this I made sidemenu.xml and headerfile.xml and I added these both sidemenu.xml and headerfile.xml to dashboard.xml now I want when I click on any options from side bar navigation it should navigate to their respective screens.

**sidemenu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    //menu one
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item

            android:id="@+id/profile_menu"
            android:icon="@drawable/profile"
            android:title="Profile" />

        <item

            android:id="@+id/home_menu"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_outline_home_24"
            android:title="Home" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/dashboard_menu"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_outline_dashboard_24"
            android:title="Dashboard" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/services_icon"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_outline_miscellaneous_services_24"
            android:title="Services" />

    </group>
    // menu two
    <group

        android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item android:title="Authentication">


            <menu>

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/login_menu"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_login_24"
                    android:title="Login" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/logout_menu"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_outline_logout_24"
                    android:title="Logout" />


            </menu>
        </item>

    </group>

    //menu three

    <item android:title="Sharing">


        <menu>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/share_menu"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_share_24"
                android:title="Share" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/refer_menu"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_send_24"
                android:title="Refer" />


        </menu>
    </item>


</menu>
```

**activity_dashboard.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".dashboard"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/headerfile"
        app:menu="@menu/sidemenu" />
```

Comment: Needs some java code as well

Answer (score 0):

First, Make sure that you want to navigate different `fragment` or `layout`. If you want to navigate different `fragment` then add all IDs of `sidemenu.xml` in `mobile_navigation.xml` (make `sidemenu.xml` and `mobile_navigation.xml` id same) and if you know how to? then please add code of your `navigation`>`mobile_navigation.xml` and also code of MainActivity. Because half code cannot solve any problem.